# Why this Python code displays a TypeError when storing the sum of the cache index?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I wanted to explore other problems to practice DP (Dynamic Programming). I found this one for the staircase problem, which is similar to the Fib sequence. However, the code that I was following seemed to be off with the sum of the precomputed cache.

As far as I went through, this is from the [Daily Programming Challenges blogs](http://www.devinline.com/2016/06/staircase-problem-in-python-recursive-and-DP.html) talking about how it works. The code snippet that they use is with a Pythonic way by using a list comprehension. I already did my part but I wanted to compare how their solution can be better than mine by using the `sum` function and taking an extra variable in the function argument.

Here is the summary:
*Each entry cache[i] will contain the number of ways we can get to step i with the set X. Then, we’ll build up the array from zero using the same recurrence as before:*

This is their code example

```
def staircase(n, X):
    cache = [0 for _ in range(n + 1)]
    cache[0] = 1
    for i in range(n + 1):
        cache[i] += sum(cache[i - x] for x in X if i - x > 0)
        cache[i] += 1 if i in X else 0
    return cache[-1]
```

This is my code sample:

```
def staircase_dp(n):

    dp = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]

    dp[0] = 1
    dp[1] = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        val = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2]
        dp.insert(i, val)
    return dp[n]
```

This is my main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    steps = 6
    n = 2

    print("Number of ways to use the stairs = {0}".format(staircase(steps, n))) #This will use the example from Daily Programming Challenge and gives TypeError message.
    print("Number of ways to use the stairs = {0}".format(staircase_dp(steps))) #Mine which outputs 13
```

For their example, when I try to print it out, it gives me a TypeError message saying:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "staircase.py", line 44, in <module>
    print("Number of ways to use the stairs = {0}".format(staircase_dp(steps, n)))
  File "staircase.py", line 21, in staircase_dp
    cache[i] = sum(cache[i - x] for x in X if i - x > 0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
```

However, for my solution, I'm just creating a dynamic array from 0 to n. As we know, dp[0] and d[1] will always give a value of 1. After the second iteration, we will start computing bigger numbers and add them to another variable that holds the values of `dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2]`. Then insert the value into the stack of `dp`, which we will then return afterward.

Which I don't quite understand because I'm just trying to add the number of computed steps have been done in the cache and just return me the cache value. Is this a correct thinking?

Comment: This can't be your real code, because `staircase_dp()` only defines one parameter, but you're calling it with two arguments, which is an error.

Comment: @JohnGordon mine is taking only one argument. Theirs is taking two arguments.

Comment: Then why are you calling `staircase_dp(steps, n)` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah, I see what you mean. It is he same as theirs. Let me fix that real quick.

Comment: `Let me fix that real quick` - so, did the result/the message change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X` you have passed to the function `staircase` as a second argument is an `int` (`2`).

This:

```
steps = 6
n = 2
...
staircase(steps, n)
```

means that inside `staircase` function `X` is `2`. That in turn means that the generator on the line mentioned in your backtrace (`cache[i] += sum(cache[i - x] for x in X if i - x > 0)`) would try to get values for `x` from (iterate over) `X`. To focus just on this very problem, we can reduce the line to (this is taken from your example above, just dropping the syntactical fluff not relevant to the immediate problem):

```
(x for x in 2)
```

Which will raise the same exception as we cannot iterate oven an `int`. You cannot do something for each `x` in `2` (an `int`) as it does not have an iterator (and there really are no meaningful items to iterate over), hence the `TypeError` exception.

In other words: you probably either wanted to iterate over something else in that generator. Or pass something else (iterable) to `staircase` as its second argument.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I still don't quite understand what you meant sorry

Comment: @ZeidTisnes I've try to reword it quote a bit and be more specific to your case. Did that help?

Comment: So basically I'm trying to iterate through an `int` value won't backtrace the sum of cache[i - x] properly? And the line that you suggest `x for x in X` will not work because it will throw the same error message. Then does that mean it is a bug from their example that they were demonstrating?

Comment: No, no, no. I did not suggest the line. It's just distilled essence of your problem (exception). The point being. That for `x` in `X` literally says: for each `x` in `2` in your example, but there are no items in `2` and that is why you see that `TypeError`.

Comment: Yes! Now it clicked to my brain. Basically what I wasn't understanding is that `X` was a set or dictionary of **how many steps** I can do with the given `steps`. So, what it was being asked is to pass through a set of `n` that can be `{1, 2}` or `[1, 2]`. Thus will give me the total of steps can be done by adding each sequence of `n set`. Thank you very much :)!